# how to write method for every buttons in a list<Button> in code behind? c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, button

suppose that we have generic list of buttons and every time we run the program, unknown number of buttons will be generated and added to this list. (So the number of buttons are not always constant)
I want to know how can I able to write method (button.click) for these buttons in this list. do you have any idea to help me?

Comment: You can attach a single event handler method to the Click event of all Buttons, and identify the clicked Button via the sender argument. However, a better approach would be to use an ItemsControl with the Button in its ItemTemplate. The Button's Command property would be bound to an ICommand property in the data item class. See [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview).

Comment: Tip: To get the current clicked button write this line the `Button.Click` handler `Button button = sender as Button;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll supplement @aepot comment:

```
    private readonly List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();
    private void AddButton(Button button)
    {
        button.Click += Button_Click;
        buttons.Add(button);
    }
    private void RemoveButton(Button button)
    {
        button.Click -= Button_Click;
        buttons.Remove(button);
    }
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Checking the event source for compatibility with the Button
        // and the presence of this button in the list
        if (sender is Button button && buttons.Contains(button))
        {
            //Here you can work with the button that caused the event
        }
    }
```

But @Clemens advice is better.
It is typical for WPF to create UI-elements in XAML.
XAML is the core language of WPF.